# Receiving an "unable to resolve host address" error when using wget

Tags: networking, virtualbox, wget

New to using Linux systems and I recently bought a book with incorporated labs to teach me to use Kali Linux through Virtualbox. However, when I attempt to use wget, I receive this error:

```
Resolving hackerhousebook.com (hackerhousebook.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
wget: unable to resolve host address 'hackerhousebook.com'
```

My original command was:

```
$ wget --user username --password password https://hackerhousebook.com/files/wordlists.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a non-Ubuntu distro of Linux your question is off-topic for this forum.

You have a basic problem with DNS not working on your client or there was a temporary problem with the DNS server you are using.  Or you have no Internet connection.  There are any number of answers on this site (and all over the Internet) to help you isolate and fix whatever your particular problem is.  The hostname is indeed resolvable and reachable.  Worked fine when I tested it.

Try `ping 51.255.28.132` to determine if you have a basic network problem or just a problem resolving hostnames.  Also try `ping 8.8.8.8` to determine if you have a problem with the DNS server you are using to query. 8.8.8.8 is the IP address of the Google DNS server.

Based on your update comment it seems likely that the zone file for the site in question was unavailable at the time you tried to access the file in question.  These days, problems with DNS A records and zone files is rare but it does happen.

```
dig hackerhousebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3-Ubuntu <<>> hackerhousebook.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45756
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hackerhousebook.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hackerhousebook.com.    3537    IN  A   51.255.28.132

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 27 21:46:45 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64



wget --user username --password password https://hackerhousebook.com/files/wordlists.tgz
--2023-10-27 21:46:51--  https://hackerhousebook.com/files/wordlists.tgz
Resolving hackerhousebook.com (hackerhousebook.com)... 51.255.28.132
Connecting to hackerhousebook.com (hackerhousebook.com)|51.255.28.132|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="login with student / student"
Reusing existing connection to hackerhousebook.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

Comment: I pinged google just fine however, when I tried to ping the website's ip address I got 100% packet loss.